# BeautifulSoup web scraping: UnboundLocalError: local variable 'soup' referenced before assignment

Tags: python, python-3.x, web-scraping, beautifulsoup, python-requests

I tried web scraping with beautiful soup and requests by following a Youtube video everything went well until I landed with this error but it worked out for the mentor.

```
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

def get_data(url):
    if not response.ok:
        print('Server Responded: {}'.format(response.status_code))
    else:
        soup = BeautifulSoup(response.text, 'lxml')
    return(soup)

def get_detail_data(soup):
    try:
        title = soup.find('h1', id='itemTitle').text.strip()
    except:
        title = ''
        
    try:
        p = soup.find('span', id='prcIsum').text.strip()
        currency, price = p.split(' ')
    except:
        currency = ''
        price = ''
    
    try:
        sold = soup.find('span', class_='vi-qtyS-hot-red').a.text.strip().split(' ')[0]
    except:
        sold = ''
    
    data = {
        'title' : title,
        'currency' : currency,
        'price' : price,
        'total units sold' : sold
    }

    return data

def get_index_data(soup):
    try:
        links = soup.find_all('a', class_='s-item__link')
    except:
        links = []

    
    urls = [item.get('href') for item in links]
    return urls

def main():
    url = 'https://www.ebay.com/sch/i.html?_nkw=mens+shoes&_sacat=0'
    
    products = get_index_data(get_data(url))

    for link in products:
        data =  get_detail_data(get_data(link))


if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()
```

Answer (score 0):

In get_data you are missing making the actual request and storing in response. Then you need to assign soup = None if the response.ok is not True. Finally, elsewhere you need to test if soup is None before attempting to calls methods on it.

```
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

def get_data(url):
    
    response = requests.get(url, headers = {'User-Agent':'Mozilla/5.0'}) #this was missing
    
    if not response.ok:
        print('Server Responded: {}'.format(response.status_code))
        soup = None
    else:
        soup = BeautifulSoup(response.text, 'lxml')
    return soup

def get_detail_data(soup):
    
    try:
        title = soup.find('h1', id='itemTitle').text.strip()
    except:
        title = ''
        
    try:
        p = soup.find('span', id='prcIsum').text.strip()
        currency, price = p.split(' ')
    except:
        currency = ''
        price = ''
    
    try:
        sold = soup.find('span', class_='vi-qtyS-hot-red').a.text.strip().split(' ')[0]
    except:
        sold = ''
    
    data = {
        'title' : title,
        'currency' : currency,
        'price' : price,
        'total units sold' : sold
    }

    return data

def get_index_data(soup):
    try:
        links = soup.find_all('a', class_='s-item__link')
    except:
        links = []

    
    urls = [item.get('href') for item in links]
    return urls

def main():
    
    url = 'https://www.ebay.com/sch/i.html?_nkw=mens+shoes&_sacat=0'
    soup = get_data(url)
    
    if not soup is None:
        
        products = get_index_data(soup)
        #print(products)

        for link in products:
            
            soup = get_data(link)
            
            if not soup is None:
                
                data =  get_detail_data(soup)
                print(data)

if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()
```

Comment: Did you try running this?